# How to create a tree like structure with different views in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to create a tree view using recursive html. Everything works fine if all the nodes of the tree look similar but in my case the parent and child look different but child and grand child look same. So, I have nested a child component in the parent component and to generate grand children I just call the same child component recursively as shown below:

parent.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let div of divsArray; index as mainIdx" class="main-container" #mainDiv>
  <button (click)="addChild(mainIdx)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
  <button (click)="addSibling(mainIdx)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
  <button (click)="removeSibling(mainIdx)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
  <app-child  *ngFor="let child of div.childArray" [childData]="child"></app- 
  child>
 </div>
```

parent.component.ts

```
    divsArray: any[]=[{'childArray':[]}];

    addSibling(){
    this.divsArray.push({'childArray':[]});
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
    }

   removeSibling(divIndex: number){
    this.divsArray.splice(divIndex,1);
   }

   addChild(pIndex: number){
     this.divsArray[pIndex].childArray.push({'grandChild':[]});
   }
```

child.component.html

```
    <div class="child-container">
    <button (click)="addChild()"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    <button (click)="removeChild()"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
    <app-child *ngFor="let child of childData.grandChild;"></app-child>
    </div>
```

child.component.ts

```
   @Input() childData: any;

   addChild(){
    this.childData.grandChild.push({'greatGrandChild':[]})
  }
```

The issue which I face here is when I try to add a child for the grandchild, I get an error saying 'cannot read property grandchild of undefined'. This happens when I click the addChild button a third time (that is to add a child for the grand child).This 'grandchild' is an array in the childData object which I pass as an input property from the parent. Can someone please help me in fixing this issue or maybe suggest some way to implement a tree like structure with different views for the parent and child node . Thanks!

Comment: Hi, will you be able to create a stackblitz and post with the question?

Comment: The reason you get TypeError is that 1) you are not passing `childData` to `app-child` in child.component.html and 2) you are probably accessing properties in your model wrongly. I strongly suggest you properly specify types of your inputs (and all other properties for that matter) so that you catch such errors in build time.

Comment: @SachithRukshan done here https://angular-szempj.stackblitz.io, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szempj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Your childData seems undefined please check that data that you are passing to child component

Comment: @DanMacák thankyou so much this is what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome @Learner.123. However, I am voting to close this question as it revolves around banal mistake and code quality issues and as such won't help other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### child.component.html

```
  <app-child *ngFor="let child of childData.grandChild;" [childData]="child"></app-child>
```

Need to set the childData input

### child.component.ts

```
  addChild() {
    this.childData.grandChild.push({ grandChild: [] });
  }
```

It's extra work to access childData's children with "greatGrandChild", "greatGreatGrandChild", since you'll also have to figure out what the right field is before accessing it, and the get create the next field name and uppercase the first letter, etc.

## Edit: If you want to delete the current node and it's children when clicking the '-'

### child.component.html

```
  <app-child *ngFor="let child of childData.grandChild;" [childData]="child" (remove)="removeChildren()"></app-child>
```

### child.component.ts

```
  @Output() remove = new EventEmitter<string>();
  addChild() {
    this.childData.grandChild.push({ grandChild: [] });
  }

  removeMe() {
    this.remove.emit(null);
  }

  removeChildren() {
    this.childData.grandChild = [];
  }
```

Comment: I did this and it worked fine, but now the problem is how do I delete these. I need to delete the child whose delete button I click and its children as well.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include that, using an output. [check this angular doc for more on outputs](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component)

Comment: hey ! this works fine for all the grandchild nodes but not for the first child node

Comment: I've already given you the code for how to achieve that on the child nodes. It's the same solution using an eventemitter & output, so I'll let you figure out the implementation.